# What is the difference between RxJava 2 Cancellable and Disposable?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, rx-java2

I want to create an `Observable` from view click listener using RxJava 2. I started from the simplest implementation (I don't use lambdas here to show you different types in this method):

```
 Observable<View> viewObservable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<View>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<View> e) throws Exception {
            mNewWordView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View value) {
                    if (!e.isDisposed()) {
                        e.onNext(value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Then I thought about the way to set `onClickListener` to null if it is not needed further. I found that there are two methods with similar (as for me) names:

`e.setCancellable(Cancellable c);` and
                        `e.setDisposable(Disposable d);`

What is the difference between them and which should I use?

Comment: Where were you planning to use **setCancellable** and **setDisposable** in your code above?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Cancellable.html):

> [`Cancellable` is] A functional interface that has a single cancel method that can throw.

The `Disposable` is not a functional interface plus when implementing its `dispose()` method, you are not allowed to throw checked exceptions.

In contrast, many non-RxJava components return a `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable` which  are defined via `throws IOException` and `throws Exception` and are somewhat of a burden because you'd need try-catch it.

For example, you'd want to use `setCancellable` when you work with a file:

```
Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<byte[]> e) -> {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("raw.dat");
    e.setCancellable(fin::close);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    for (;;) {
        int r = fin.read(buffer);
        if (r < 0) {
            break;
        }
        e.onNext(buffer);
    }
    e.onComplete();
});
```

and you'd use `setDisposable` if you use a `Scheduler`:

```
Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<Event> e) -> {
    Worker worker = Schedulers.io().createWorker();
    e.setDisposable(worker);

    eventSource.onEvent(es ->
        worker.schedule(() -> e.onNext(es))
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I use `check if (!e.isDisposed())` if I use Cancellable and not Disposed?

Comment: Yes, the downstream dispose call is properly reflected via isDisposed() no matter what resources you have.

Comment: For this basic case, you don't really need it but in case you want to emit an `onError`, it is advised to an isDisposed() check because if the emitter is disposed, the error will be routed to the global error handler which crashes an Android app often unexpectedly.

Comment: Nowadays it's safer to use `tryOnError` rather than `onError` + `isDisposed`

Answer (score 22):

The `Cancellable` ends up getting wrapped into a `Disposable` so the final effect is the same for either call. The difference is that `Disposable` has more features that you might not want to implement, so the simple `Cancellable` interface is there as an alternative.

If you just want to dispose something when the observable ends use `Cancellable`. If you have a resource that might be disposed because of some external reason you want to implement `Disposable` to implement the `Disposable.isDisposed()` method.

Do note that the methods are mutually exclusive. Only a single disposable or cancellable can be registered at once. Calling both overwrites the first one.

Comment: Thank you. Should I use check `if (!e.isDisposed())` if I use Cancellable and not Disposed?

Comment: akarnokd is one of the RxJava developers and his example does not use it so that check if probably not required. As far as I know such a check is only required on `onError` calls because an error on a disposed observable will go to the global exception handler.

Comment: ~"**some external reason**".  What kind of reason for this?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky For example if you're listening for events from another system and that system broadcasts that it has ended, you can report that it has already been disposed, instead of potentially wasting time unregistering for events.