# How to correctly control emissions for defined Scheduler in created Observable

Tags: rx-java, observable, scheduler, rx-java2, emitter

I am using RxJava2 and let's say I have this Observable:

```
Observable
   .create(emitter -> 
      SomeDependency.registerCallback(data -> emitter.onNext(data))
   )
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

It observes some asynchronous logic and then emits whatever it gets from it. Important to know is, that in the registered callback, the data is delivered on a thread handled by `SomeDependency`. As a consequence this causes all `emitter`'s emissions to downstream to be delivered on that thread, ignoring defined `Scheduler`.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283760/1618316 there is a hint from @akarnokd that indicates a way to redirect data to correct thread using `Scheduler.Worker`. Modified example for such approach would look as following:

```
Observable
   .create(emitter -> {
      final Worker worker = Schedulers.trampoline().createWorker();
      emitter.setDisposable(worker);
      SomeDependency.registerCallback(data -> 
         worker.schedule(() -> emitter.onNext(data))
      )
   })
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

> NOTE: `trampoline()` creates a `Scheduler` for a current thread. In our case the `io()` thread as we have defined that one to create our Observable on.

The thing is, that when creating this kind of Observables you usually need not only to `registerCallback()` but also to `unregisterCallback()`. In common scenarios, you put `unregisterCallback()` into an `emitter`'s `Disposable`. However, as you can see, our `emitter` already has a `Disposable`, not being able to set an another one. If the second `Disposable` would be set, then the previous one is unset and disposed.

Do you have any ideas on how to approach this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `CompositeDisposable`.

> A disposable container that can hold onto multiple other disposables.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks.