# How to create Observables and update them with Retrofit later RxJava?

Tags: android, observable, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

Basically I need to create a List of Observables without initial values. I subscribe to that list of Observables and will provide required results based on the responses from all Observables. I use zip operator.

The problem is that I need to create Observables initially, add them to the list and use zip operator. Only later I do network request with Retrofit and I need to update the value of observable in the list so my whole zip operator will be working.

However, I did not find a way to force update an observable in the list with the response from Retrofit. It seems very easy but I did not found any solutions.. only idea is to use tons of subjects and add them to the list instead...

```
 List<Observable<Object>> listObservables = new ArrayList<>();
    //Adding initial request
    Observable<Object> testObservable = RetrofitFactory.create().startProcess();
    listObservables.add(testObservable);

    Observable.concatDelayError(listObservables).subscribe(response ->
            {
                //This is where all results should be managed
                Log.d("response", String.valueOf(response));
            },
            error ->
            {
                Log.d("response", String.valueOf(error));
            });
    //Actual request occurs much later in application

    listObservables.get(0).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(response ->
    {
        // the response of this, should notify concatDelayError
        Log.d("respoonse", String.valueOf(response));
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand completely your question. Could you post your code in order to understand better your problem?

Comment: Ok, I have updated :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to implement *sub requests model*. For this task you can break chain of operators to different execution flows and combine it back, for example, with `zip` operator. With this approach you can create completely independent data flow with sole trigger.

```
Subject<Event> eventSubject = PublishSubject.create();

Observable<TriggerObject> mainRequest = eventSubject.flatMap((event) -> 
        RetrofitFactory.create().startProcess());
Observable<FirstSubResult> firstSubRequest = mainRequest.flatMap(tigger -> {
    // make first sub request
});
Observable<SecondSubResult> secondSubRequest = mainRequest.flatMap(tigger -> {
    // make second sub request
});
Observable<CompleteResult> resultObservable = Observable.zip(firstSubRequest, secondSubRequest,
        // zip function
        (first, second) -> {
            // combine result of sub requests to complete result object  
        });
```

Now you can start request flow by your event:

```
// post your event. On button clicked for evxample
eventSubject.doOnNext(yourEvent);
```

*NOTE: this answer show main idea of chaining data flow sequences. This applicable to to other types of requests, and you can use this approach without retrofit*

Comment: Wow really genious slution.. It might be a case that need just this case

Comment: Still not what I need exactly...

Observable<SecondSubResult> secondSubRequest = mainRequest.flatMap(tigger -> {
    // make second sub request
});
this should have additional trigger, because it does not only needs to wait for startProcess() to complete but actually for user to press button ...

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov for this purpose you can use `Subject` or [convenient libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33652347/3926506). I've updated my answer